# applescript: automatic response to specific message

Tags: applescript

My girlfriend is trying to use tiktok less, so she has enabled a feature where every time she opens the app it texts me "(her name) is on Tiktok." to hold herself accountable

I'm trying to use applescript on my mac to do the following:

1. see if I'm receiving an iMessage from her that tells me she's on Tiktok
2. then send the message "you've logged into tiktok x times today" where x starts at 1, increments each time I receive the message that she's on tiktok, and resets every day

my current script returns the following syntax error:

> Expected “given”, “into”, “with”, “without” or other parameter name but found identifier.

here is my current code which I've tried to piece together from a number of resources:

```
using terms from application "Messages"

    property today : missing value
    property current_count : 1
    
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat with eventDescription
        "girlfriend is on Tiktok."
        if name of theBuddy = "my girlfriend's name" then
    
        tell application "Messages"
            send "you have logged into tiktok" & current_count & " times today" to theBuddy
            increment()
        
            on increment()
                set currentDate to short date string of (current date)
                if currentDate is not today then
                    set today to currentDate
                    set current_count to 1
                end if
                set current_count to current_count + 1
            end increment
    
        end tell

    end message received

... (a bunch of irrelevant code to avoid error -1078)
```

the code error occurs at the line beginning with "on message received ..." at the word "received"

Comment: If you are running **macOS** 10.13.4. or newer then there is no longer an **AppleScript** _handler_ in **Messages** So, it doesn't matter what error you're getting if that is the case.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the _code_ it looks like your are missing an `end if` for the `if name` _block_ and an `end using terms from` for the `using terms from application "Messages"` _block_ and the `increment` _handler_ shouldn't be inside of the `on message received` _handler_, just to name a few things that do not look right.

Comment: Is there any way I can implement something like this if there's no handler for Messages at all? is it impossible to automate in Messages now?